# Blazor js interop empty DataTransfer API items after calling dotnet method

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I have a Blazor server side project and I am trying to interop with js.
Everything works as expected except this strange (for me) behavior

Inside a js module I have registered an ondrop event and I am assigning the dataTransfer items from the event to a const;

After awaiting the dotnet method the const items is kind of "resetting".

```js
dropzone.addEventListener("drop", dropHandler, false);

const dropHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const items = event.dataTransfer.items;
    console.log(items);
    // outputs: DataTransferItemList {0: DataTransferItem, length: 1}
    dotnetRefObject.InvokeMethodAsync("FireAndForget");
    console.log(items);
    // outputs: DataTransferItemList {0: DataTransferItem, length: 1}
    const result = await dotnetRefObject.invokeMethodAsync('MethodWithReturn');
    console.log(result);
    //ouputs: true
    console.log(items);
    //ouputs: DataTransferItemList {length: 0}
}
```

```cs
[JSInvokable]
public async Task<bool> MethodWithReturn()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a JS expert, but I think declaring `const items` just takes a reference to the datatransfer items and store the reference as a constant. The underlying `items` being referenced can still change. In addition I don't think events are natively async, so this is going to fire and forget in JS as well - and so I believe the dataTransfer is probably cleared down while you await the .NET method. If you clone the datatransfer items instead that should solve the problem I would hope

Comment: @MisterMagoo thanks for the valuable info. cloning didn't work either

Comment: I was right about one thing then - I am not a JS expert 

Comment: I have managed to overcome the problem by getting the entries before the awaitable dotnet call. i.e. const getEntriesFromEvent = (event) => {
    const items = event.dataTransfer.items;
    const entries = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        const item = items[i];
        const entry = item.webkitGetAsEntry()
        entries.push(entry);
    }
    return entries;
}